# React Native Image Next to Multiline Text?

Tags: image, react-native, text, icons

I have a checkbox with text next to it, requiring an Image (which is an icon) attached to the last word for more information. I haven't found a reliable way to do this. The only way is either breaking up the text into different chunks and wrapping the parent or absolute positioning of the icon - both of which end up positioned differently on different devices depending on size.

When I add the image inside of the text, I get a weird background image of a file icon.
[image]

When I keep it outside, It just defaults to the end of the text block:
[image]

My code snippet:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Checkbox style={styles.checkbox} checked={agreedChecked} />
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }}>
    <Text style={[ styles.label]}>Yes, I agree to using this payment method for automatic monthly charges.</Text>
    <Image source={require('../../assets/Icon_Info.png')} />
  </View>
</View>
```

Blown up to show weird file background:
(note it does not have the background when outside the text element)

[image]

Comment: depending on your requirements, you might consider using emoji ℹ️

Comment: @MikeM that's a good idea! I'll check and see if they have an emoji close to it. It does have to look identical per requirements though

Comment: FWIW, here's the unicode page. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f6c8/index.htm  I think presentation is usually based on the font used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this, it was a known bug and is fixed in React Native 0.61.4!

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/26653

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply copy & paste this code segment and try it? It works for me. If you want, I can create a repo for you.

Github Example Repo

https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-text-ends-with-icon-example

```
import React from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
          {/* <Checkbox style={styles.checkbox} checked={agreedChecked} /> */}
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: "#757575" }}>
              Yes, I agree to using this payment method for automatic monthly
              charges.{" "}
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
                <Image
                  style={{ height: 15, width: 15 }}
                  source={require("./assets/icon.png")}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Position wise, this works; however, I'm still seeing that strange background behind the image. Adding the example (super enlarged) to the question above - watch for edit.

Comment: I do not have a strange background like that. I'm going to create an example repo, can you please try it?

Comment: @Almost_Ashleigh can you try with this? https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-text-ends-with-icon-example I believe that your asset has a problem.

Comment: You are totally right, your image example works perfectly!! I'll dig into my image asset and see what is going on and provide an update here just for general curiosity haha. Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that we found the problem :) Have fun